# Is this algorithmic proof valid for proving every open set in R^1 is the union of an at most countable collection of disjoint segments?

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I am retired and going through Rudin's Principles of Mathematics via self study.  I am working on Problem #29, Chapter 2:  Prove every open set in $R^1$ is the union of an at most countable collection of disjoint segments.

My main question is: when the cardinality N of a set is not finite, is the For loop using N as the endpoint valid in a construction proof?  My proof is below.

Note:  this is the first time I have posted on Stack Exchange.  Any comments about formatting, posting, etc. would be appreciated.

Let E be the open set in question, where $E \subset R^1$.

If $E=\emptyset$, since $\emptyset$ is open in $R^1$ and $\{\emptyset\}$ is finite (and therefore at most countable), then the statement is true. $\therefore$ Assume $E \ne \emptyset$.

From Exercise #22 in Rudin, $R^1$ is separable, and from #23 has a countable base, call it $V =$ {$V_\alpha$}.  Note that in the proof of #23, the countable base used was a collection of neighborhoods, $N_r(p)$, where $r \in Q$ and $p$ was an element of a countable dense subset of a metric space $X$.  Here, $X=R^1$, so the collection of neighborhoods $N_r(p)$ in $R^1$ is a collection of segments, since $N_r(p)$ in $R^1$ is a segment. $\therefore V$ is a countable collection of segments.

$\therefore$ From $V=${$V_\alpha$}, let {$G_\alpha$} = {$V_\alpha \in V$ such that $V_\alpha \cap E \ne \emptyset$}.

$\therefore$ {$G_\alpha$} is an at most countable collection of segments, and $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha}G_\alpha = E$, using the definition of a base.  From {$G_\alpha$}, we will now construct a collection of connected open disjoint segments {$E_i$} of $E$ such that $E=\bigcup\limits_i E_i$.

Note that if $A$ and $B$ are segments in $R^1$ and $A\cap B \ne \emptyset$, then $A\cup B$ is a segment in $R^1$.

Start with $E_1 = G_1$, and let {$R_\alpha$} $=$ {$G_\alpha$}$ - G_1$. {$R_\alpha$} represents the remaining base elements of {$G_\alpha$}.

Let {$H_\alpha$}={$R_\alpha$}, used as a holding collection of base elements, and {$H_\alpha$} will change in the examining iterations below.  Initially assign $T=E_1=G_1$, a testing set to compare with the remaining sets in {$R_\alpha$}.

Now, as in a computer algorithm, and comments are in parentheses,

Let $N = $ cardinality of {$R_\alpha$}

$j=1$   (initialize counter for $E_j$)

Do while $N>0$   (if $N=0$, $\bigcup\limits_{k}E_k = E$)

----For i = 1 to N  (go through every set in $\{R_\alpha\}$)

--------if $T\cap R_i \ne \emptyset$ then

------------$E_j = E_j \cup R_i$      (expand $E_j$ by $R_i$)

------------{$H_\alpha$} = {$R_\alpha$} $- R_i$  (store adjustment of {$R_\alpha$})

--------end if

----Next

----if {$R_\alpha$} = {$H_\alpha$} then    (so, $E_j$ hasn't changed)

--------$j=j+1$        (construct the next $E_j$)

--------$E_j = \emptyset$     (initialize)

----end if

----{$R_\alpha$} = {$H_\alpha$}      (update status of remaining sets)

----$N = $ cardinality of {$R_\alpha$}    (update for For loop)

----{$H_\alpha$} = {$R_\alpha$}          (reinitialize $\{H_\alpha\}$)

----if {$R_\alpha$} $\ne \emptyset$ then $T=R_1$     (reinitialize testing set $T$)

Loop   (continue as long as {$R_\alpha$} $\ne \emptyset$)

From the above construction, $E_j \cap E_k = \emptyset$ for $j \ne k$, so the open sets $E_j$ (which are segments) are disjoint.  Since every member of {$G_\alpha$} has been assigned to some $E_j$, $\bigcup\limits_{j=1}E_j = E$ since $\bigcup\limits_{\alpha}G_\alpha = E$. And since {$G_\alpha$} is at most countable, {$E_j$} is at most countable.